# In java what is the difference between Systemloader,bootstraploader&ExtensionLoader?

Tags: java

I know about class loader, which loads and verifies bytecodes,
but why are there different types of class loader?  Specifically Systemloader, bootstraploader and ExtensionLoader.  What do they do?

Comment: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077260/learn-javahe-basics-of-java-class-loaders/learn-java/the-basics-of-java-class-loaders.html

Comment: Thanku useful to know about classLoader But they have not answered the difference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of the class loaders that you mention are chained together.  Most Java programs (excluding J2EE and containers) use the System Class Loader directly.  More complex Java programs, such as Tomcat use custom class loaders to segregate different applications.   A request to load a class starts by checking a cache to see if it is already loaded, if it is not then a search begins by perculating to the root of the chain and back again.  The root of the chain is the Bootstrap Class Loader, and it searches in rt.jar (and has special security restrictions as this is the heart of the Java libs, we do not want people replacing java.lang.String behind our backs for example).  If rt.jar does not hold the class, then the extension class loader checks under /lib/ext/*.jar and is part of the Java Extension mechanism and finally the system class loader which is used for the class path and contains 'our' code.

[image]